# Unknown column 'this' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have tried my best to find the answer to my questions in previous threads but just can't find what i need, i have a function in my php document that updates a column (follow (varchar)) in the users table with a pre-defined variable, when a_username matches the sessionnaeme, however this function returns the error "Unknown column 'this' in 'where clause'" this is the tabel layout: [Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HkPg.jpg)
I'm new to php so any help would be much appreciated! (sorry if question is unclear please ask any questions you may have) The php function is below.
Thanks so much in advance!!

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sessionname = $_SESSION['user'];
    $follow = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['addedname']);
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET follow =" .$follow. " WHERE a_username =".$sessionname."";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if($result !== false) {
        header("Location: ./Profile.php?Follow=success");            
        exit;
    } else {
             echo "Fail";
            }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for string values  you should use quote around values

```
 $sql = "UPDATE users SET follow ='" .$follow. "' WHERE a_username ='".$sessionname."';";
```

anyway you should avoid PHP vars  in SQL. you area at risk for sql injection  .. you should look how you SQL driver manager prepared  statement  and binding param  instead

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Unfortunately I am now being returned this error "Unknown column 'this' in 'field list'". Also thanks for the suggestion regarding the sql injection and php variables, i will take this into consideration!

Comment: answer  updated ..  if the follow is a string alos for this column you need  quote

Comment: Awesome honestly thanks so much, hours of frustration resolved!! Thanks so much mate!

Comment: @AnthonyWaymouth   .. thanks  .. but take really a deep look for prepared  statement and binding param  .. sqlinject  could be very dangerous

Comment: appreciate that and defiantly will have a look! Any ideas on how to make it so that the $follow variable only adds to the column so if the was, hello already in the follow collum and once the above statement is submited the collum will only add the text (say, hi) so that follow would then be, hello hi

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do it using bound parameters in MySqli.

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET follow = ? WHERE a_username = ?";

 $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['addedname'], $_SESSION['user']);
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();

 if(!$result->num_rows === 0){

   header("Location: ./Profile.php?Follow=success");            
   exit;

 } else {

   echo 'Fail';

 }

 $stmt->close();
```

Here is a great beginners guide to parameterized queries using MySqli.  Bookmark this link and refer to it often.  [Prevent SQl Injection](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)